# While executing my magento file i am getting fatal error

Tags: magento2.2.2

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1769107328 bytes) in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento_final\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime.php on line 38

can u please give this sloution

Comment: Refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/209993) link.

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate more memory to the php by changing `memory_limit` from php.ini in xamp.
find

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

it may be different, then 128M, you can add more memory and try.

Comment: I would recommend assign atleast  1gb of memory for Magento 2.
Also I have noticed that my magento is running much slower on xampp than on virtual box with vagrant.