# Magento 2 Allowed Memory exhausted error in Magento 2.3/Wampp

Tags: magento2.3, wamp

I have an error when i add module..

so i run below command but also display error that below when run command from root,

**php magento setup:di:compile**

[image]

How i fix it?

i already allow memory limit to 4G

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way:

`php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile`

**OR**

Edit PHP.ini settings, in this case is the memory_limit

`memory_limit = 768M
max_execution_time = 18000`

change memory and execution time limit.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i already increase memory_limit and max_execution_time but error still coming.

Comment: Have you tried by adding ini_set('memory_limit','-1'); in index.php

Comment: It might help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209976/magento-2-2-2-allowed-memory-size-of-792723456-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-alloc check this link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running this command:

`php -dmemory_limit=1024M bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Sometime it occurs that the sufficient memory id not available for M2 command to execute.So we set the memory limit for it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: sir i am on window 10 not in linux etc

Comment: In that case use this php -dmemory_limit=1024M bin/magento setup:di:compile..also did you restart your server after changing the memory limit?

Comment: i need php -dmemory_limit=1024M this command everytime?

Comment: did it work? yes when ever there is issue of memory you can use it.

Comment: i don't want to use this comment every time but right now i needed.i want to get lifetime solution

Comment: You can increase the memory limit in php.ini file and restart the server after that. as it doesnt reflect if you wont start the server

Comment: i already do this but error still same

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out which php.ini file your are loading first. run the following command to find your **php.ini**

```
php --ini
```

The output will show you where is the **php.ini** you are loading now, and locate the file and change the

```
memory_limit = 768M

max_execution_time = 18000
```

after that restart your **`httpd service.`**