# Magento 2 is giving me Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted when i am trying to save product

Tags: magento2, php-7, zend-framework

I am getting following errros

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 73400328 bytes) in public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. in public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(93): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 /var/www/modernlamps.dk/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) #3 public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute in public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 235
```

Guys, can you help me to fix this issue?

I have tried to allocate 2GB ram but still having the same error.

- Magento Version: 2.3.1
- Php 7.2
- Nginx

Comment: you change `memory_limit`  in php.ini

Comment: O have tried that but no luck

Comment: you check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209976/magento-2-2-2-allowed-memory-size-of-792723456-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-alloc or not ???

Answer (score 0):

You should change the memory_limit from php.ini into as memory_limit = 536870912