# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in Magento customer Create

Tags: magento2, fatal-error

I got this issue when creating the customer in magneto 2.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/VersionControl/Snapshot.php on line 47
```

due to this reason, I increased the memory limit up to 8 GB. but the issue remains.

```
/**
 * Register snapshot of entity data, for tracking changes
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $entity
 * @return void
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedLocalVariable)
 */
public function registerSnapshot(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $entity)
{
    $metaData = $this->metadata->getFields($entity);
    $filteredData = array_intersect_key($entity->getData(), $metaData);
    $data = array_merge($metaData, $filteredData);
    $this->snapshotData[get_class($entity)][$entity->getId()] = $data;
}
```

issue raised in this line
**$data = array_merge($metaData, $filteredData);**

vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/VersionControl/Snapshot.php

What solution we need to provide this.

Comment: where you are getting this issue are you doing any custom code?

Comment: /vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/VersionControl/Snapshot.php on line 47

Comment: @WaqarAli 'customer/account/createpost/'

Comment: this error usually occurs when you use getData() method on Model Object please check is this any case in Your Custom Code

Comment: hi @WaqarAli I updated question with code which is error occured.
could you check it?

Answer (score 0):

This may be worked.

[Magento 2.2.2 : Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 184320 bytes)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209976/magento-2-2-2-allowed-memory-size-of-792723456-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-alloc/209993#209993)

But none of the above options not worked for me.

My server is nginx. It memory limit defined in /etc/nginx/magento.conf

open the file and search

```
fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=
```

inside the below block

```
location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503|info|cleanopcache)\.php$ {

}
```

after found that line, the memory limit has to set as 6144M

fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=6144M \n max_execution_time=600";

after that, it works fine.

you able to find how much memory limit set in your Magento projects via debug log.

make log with ini_get('memory_limit');

hope this helps you all.