# Memory exhaust when using custom module collection

Tags: error, collection, magento2.4, memory

I'm trying to create a custom module with the usual model, resourcemodel and collection.

My problem is that whenever I try to use the collection, magento runs out of memory.
The collection only has one row and no more than 10 columns. I have increased the memory limit to 4G.

I have done this several times in earlier versions of magento (2.3.3) and never had such problems. Right now I'm on Magento 2.4.2.

Here are my files :

Collection :

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Offer;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\Offer', 'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Offer');
    }
}
```

Model :

```php
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Model;


class Offer extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\Offer');
    }

}
```

ResourceModel :

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel;

class Offer extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('vendor_module_offer', 'offer_id');
    }
}
```

And how I try to use it :

TestBlock.php

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Directory\Helper\Data as DirectoryHelper;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as JsonHelper;

class TestBlock extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    private \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Offer\CollectionFactory $_offerCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Offer\CollectionFactory $offerCollectionFactory,
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = [],
        ?JsonHelper $jsonHelper = null,
        ?DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper = null
    ) {
        $this->_offerCollectionFactory = $offerCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data, $jsonHelper, $directoryHelper);
    }

    public function getOffers()
    {
        return $this->_offerCollectionFactory->create()->getFirstItem()->getData();
    }
}
```

test.phtml

```php
<?php
/**
 * @var $block Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\TestBlock
 */

echo $block->getOffers();
```

And finally, the error I'm getting :
[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: try var_dump(echo $block->getOffers()); or try print_r(echo $block->getOffers());

Comment: @GohilRajesh you can't var_dump(echo ...), and I've tried both var_dump($block->getOffers()) and print_r($block->getOffers()) and I get the same result.

Comment: ohh.. its my mistake putted echo inside var dump

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue with memory leaking. In this sitution following links help for me. I hope you also helpful following links

[Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in Magento customer Create](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/337591/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-268435456-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate)

[Magento 2.2.2 : Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 184320 bytes)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209976/magento-2-2-2-allowed-memory-size-of-792723456-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-alloc/337901#337901)

Comment: Thanks, but sadly these aren't working for me. My memory limit is set correctly, I could set it to 10G and it would still crash

Comment: Did you set memory limit in php level ? Could you check log in your project by using logging this code  ini_get('memory_limit'). Sometimes it not be in 10G

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was dumb.

The error comes from my model's  `$this->_init()`. I actually put my model path instead of the required resourceModel path.

Here's the fixed part

Model :

```php
protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Offer');
    }
```

Comment: happy to hear u found solution