# Memory exhausted in NoSuchEntityException.php on line 50

Tags: magento2.3, memory, no-such-entity-exception

I have recently imported customers in Magento 2.3.2 - when logging in as a customer I'm receiving a:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php on line 50
```

When I review `NoSuchEntityException.php:50` I do see this :

```
    public static function singleField($fieldName, $fieldValue)
{
    return new self(
        new Phrase(
            'No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue',
            [
                'fieldName' => $fieldName,
                'fieldValue' => $fieldValue
            ]
        )
    );
}
```

However, It seems to be "cached" the exceptions. Or maybe it's a queue stacking up.

I've tried:

- Cache clear
- Cache flush
- DI Compile

I've tried to search for this exact issue, but I cannot seem to find anything that helps.

What can I do???

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209976/magento-2-2-2-allowed-memory-size-of-792723456-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-alloc

Comment: @BhavinGohil not the same issue. Here it dies before exception get's written.

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Magento-2-3-1-Magento-framework-Exception-NosuchEntityException/td-p/143733

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23411

Comment: https://blog.expertrec.com/magento-2-no-such-entity-with-customerid/

Comment: @BhavinGohil still not the same thing? It dies WHEN making an exception, ergo no exceptions is written.  Please read my post

Answer (score 0):

Try following commands:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade php bin/magento
> setup:static-content:deploy php bin/magento setup:di:compile php
> bin/magento cache:flush php bin/magento cache:clean
>
> //To run command forcefully php -f bin/magento
>
> //To run command with memory limit 4G php -d memory_limit=4G
> bin/magento
>
> //To run command with max memory limit php -d memory_limit=-1
> bin/magento

If you are still facing issue then try following settings:

> 1. [Magento2-root-folder]/index.php ini_set('memory_limit',256);
>
> OR
>
> ini_set('memory_limit','-1'); Check current memory_limit value using
> CLI:
>
> 1. php -r ""echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;""
> 2. php -i | grep memory

If the issue are still persist then increase the memory limit (e.g., up to 2048M) in the following places:

> 1. [Magento2-root-folder]/.user.ini -> memory_limit = 768M
> 2. [Magento2-root-folder]/.htaccess (2 places) -> php_value memory_limit 768M
> 3. [Magento2-root-folder]/pub/.user.ini -> memory_limit = 768M
> 4. [Magento2-root-folder]/pub/.htaccess (2 places) -> php_value memory_limit 768M