# Magento 2 Error when Inject class in Model file

Tags: magento2.4.3

I have created model file but when I'm going to inject additional class in the constructor I'm getting the error and page is not working.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Vendor\QueAnswer\Helper\Data $qaHelper,
    \Vendor\QueAnswer\Model\ResourceModel\QueAnswer $resource,
    \Vendor\QueAnswer\Model\ResourceModel\QueAnswer\Collection $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    $this->qaHelper = $qaHelper;
}

protected function _construct()
{
    //parent::_construct();
    $this->_init(ResourceModel\QueAnswer::class);
}
```

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /var/www/html/m2site/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php on line 150

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /var/www/html/m2site/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php on line 151

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /var/www/html/m2site/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php on line 91

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the memory limit in your `bin/magento` command: `php -d memory_limit=4G bin/magento`.

Example: `php -d memory_limit=4G bin/magento s:d:c`

You are also able to increase the memory limit in many ways, check: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/209993/39884

Btw, you should replace your `__construct` method with the following code:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Vendor\QueAnswer\Helper\Data $qaHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    $this->qaHelper = $qaHelper;
}
```

Comment: I have also tried this but not working.

Comment: you have to remove **generated** folder then re-compile DI: `rm -rf generated && bin/magento s:d:c`, then check if it works or not.

Comment: Not working. Still getting error Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/html/m2site/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php on line 75

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

you should replace the code

```
\Vendor\QueAnswer\Model\ResourceModel\QueAnswer $resource,
\Vendor\QueAnswer\Model\ResourceModel\QueAnswer\Collection $resourceCollection = null,
```

with the code below

```
 \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource,
\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection,
```

then

```
rm -rf generated
php bin/magento s:d:c
```

I think it will work.

Comment: Still not working.